# Can I tag my question as referring to a specific language?

Tags: support

I have a question about my Music Fans Stack Exchange post: [Meanings in "Mon Maquis" by Alizée](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/7151/meanings-in-mon-maquis-by-aliz%c3%a9e)

I wanted to tag this question as "French," but I got the message that that was a new tag. Is there a straightforward way to indicate that the question relates to lyrics in a specific language?

I'm surely not the first person wanting to do this, so I would assume that we don't have language takes because it's not considered a good idea. It seems like a good and rather obvious idea to me. Can someone explain, please?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we want to have tags for each language, that would muck up the usability.  And, to be fair, we can't lump them all into "foreign-language" because English is a foreign language to some.  If we had more users I might see how this could be helpful, but based on our small user base I'd say tagging languages isn't necessary at this time.